# Group by DataFrame with list and sum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas Dataframe **df** and I want to Group by **text** column with aggregation of:

- Stack the **english_word** and return the list
- Sum the **count** column

Now I only can do either making the english_word list or sum the count column. I try to do that, but it return error. How to do both of that aggregation?

In simple, what I want:

**text**

saya eat chicken

**english_word**

[eat,chicken]

**count**

2

```
df.groupby('text', as_index=False).agg({'count' : lambda x: x.sum(), 'english_word' : lambda x: x.list()})
```

This is the example of **df**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['Saya eat chicken', 'Saya eat chicken'], 
                   'english_word': ['eat', 'chicken'],
                   'count': [1,1]})
```

Comment: Hello, welcome :)) [Please read this post on how to provide a great pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and [refer to this one on how to provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and revise your question accordingly so people in the community can easily help you. You don't need to post the actual dataframe, just a simple representation of what does it contain.

Comment: Please provide sample input table, and a sample of wanted output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there, you can do:

```
s = df.groupby('text').agg({'word': list, 'num': 'count'}).reset_index()

  text       word  num
0  bla  [i, love]    2
```

> **Sample Data**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['bla','bla'],
                  'word':['i','love'],
                  'num':[1,2,]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
def summarise(df):
     return Series(dict(Count = df['count'].sum(), 
                        Words = "{%s}" % ', '.join(df['english_word'])))

new_df = df.groupby('text', as_index=False).agg({'count' : lambda x:x.sum(), 'english_word' : lambda x: x.list()})

new_df.groupby('text').apply(summarise)
```